# Problema Iterador en un ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, junit, iteradores, junit-5

El problema reside en que al hacer un debug en el método testIterator, en el primer assertEquals me salta una excepción de tipo "InvocationTargetException", pero no llego a enterder del todo a que error se refiere.
El siguiente código pertenece a una clase de JUnit5 y que a partir de ella tengo que ir corrigiendo los errores de la clase ArrayList.

```
public class TestArrayList {

private ArrayList<String> lista1 = new ArrayList<String>();
private Integer[] enteros = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}; // autoboxing
private ArrayList<Integer> lista2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(enteros);

public void testIterator() {
    Iterator<String> iteradorString = lista1.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> iteradorEnteros = lista2.iterator();

    assertEquals(new Integer(1), iteradorEnteros.next());
    assertEquals(new Integer(2), iteradorEnteros.next());

    assertTrue(iteradorEnteros.hasNext());
    assertFalse(iteradorString.hasNext());
    
    try {
        iteradorString.next();
        fail("Debería haber lanzado una excepción");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "No hay más elementos en la lista");

    }

    lista1.add("Ana");
    lista1.add("Juan");

    assertEquals("Ana", iteradorString.next());
    assertEquals("Juan", iteradorString.next());

    iteradorEnteros.remove();
    assertEquals(new Integer(4), lista2.get(2));
    int index = 2;
    try {
        iteradorString.remove();
        fail("Debería haber lanzado una excepción");
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "Indice: " + index + ", Tamaño: " + lista1.size);
    }

}
```

Dentro de la clase ArrayList, el método iterator y la clase ArrayListIterator que serían en todo caso los que tendría que modificar para solucionar el problema.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
return null;
// Devuelve una instancia de ArrayListIterator}

private class ArrayListIterator implements Iterator<E> {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Podrías poner el stacktrace de la excepción, indicando en qué línea te salta? Y no entiendo bien lo de "los [métodos] que tendría que modificar para solucionar el problema" ¿te refieres a que has creado tu propia clase ArrayList?